# Syncing local changes to minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I already have stakater reloader to redeploy the pods whenever configmap is updated, however it only happens when I run helm upgrade to persist the changes from local index.php to my minikube. How can I do so that after any changes to index.php all changes are persisted to minikube without running any additional commands?